# Getting a date from a datetimepicker into mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker in my app which end users will use to choose when an item will be deferred to.

If the user picks a date and hits confirm, the date should be dropped into the mysql record for this entry, but I cant seem to get VB to update the DATE value  :(

I'm thinking its probably a formatting thing, but I'm not sure how to best overcome this.

He're the code behind the 'confirm' button.

```
  Private Sub ConfirmDefer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConfirmDefer.Click

  Dim deferdate As Date = Format(nb_deferdatepicker.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")
  updatesql("newbusiness_dataset", "action_date", deferdate, "id='" &       nb_prospectid.Text & "'")

  nb_defer_schedule.Visible = False
  nb_defer_schedule.Enabled = False

  End Sub
```

The 'UpdateSQL' bit is a function I use to simplify updating the db.
Its output SQL command is as follows:

```
  UPDATE newbusiness_dataset SET action_date='20/02/2016' WHERE id='100001'
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: is action_date `datetime` in database?

Comment: Its 'Date', not 'DateTime', as i'm not bothered about time at all, just date.
I did also try changing it to Datetime to see if it made a difference, but still it does not update the record.

Comment: Change it to `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Lowercase 'mm' is minutes though, and causes exception...

Conversion from string "2016-18-22" to type 'Date' is not valid.

Comment: If this question is answered, please click the check mark so this question can be removed from the Unanswered list

Answer (score 1):

> output SQL command is as follows:
>       `UPDATE newbusiness_dataset SET action_date='20/02/2016' WHERE id='100001'`

The way your function is updating is likely incorrect.  Ticks are not all-purpose SQL variable delimiters.  They are used to indicate text: so your method is converting the `Date` to string, and possibly the same for Id which are typically numeric.  Similarly, this code:

```
Dim deferdate As Date = Format(nb_deferdatepicker.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Using `Option Strict On` this will not compile.  `Format` is a function returning a string, but the code is assigning the result to a `DateTime` var.  There is simply no reason to try to format a `DateTimePicker` value, because it already is a date, and the MySQL NET data provider objects know how to pass a NET date to the db.

Given the resulting SQL, I also suspect you are using concatenation to glue bits of string together for the query.  This is **very dangerous** and can lead to [SQL injection](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) attacks. It will also fail on names like `Charles D'Artagnan` or `Pete's Plumbing`.

SQL Parameters prevent this, allow you to pass typed data to the data provider and result in easy to read and maintain SQL.  The general approach would be like this:

```vb
Dim rows As Int32
Dim SQL = "UPDATE Table_Name SET colA = @p1, colB = @p2, colC = @p3 WHERE Id = @p4"

Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, dbcon)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.String).Value = myFrm.TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = intVar
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
        ' the where:
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = intVarA

        dbcon.Open()
        rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
End Using
```

- The USING blocks dispose of the things which should be disposed of to free resources
- A new connection and command object are created, used and disposed of.  Often helpers like to reuse these, but especially with the DBCommand object there is nothing reusable about them.
- Since `ExecuteNonQuery` will report how many rows are affected, `rows` captures that result.

The magic, such as it is, is here:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = datetimeVar
```

Using parameters you can pass an actual `DateTime` variable instead of text. You can use `myDateTimePicker.Value` because the value **is** a `DateTime`.

- For a `Date` column, using `MySqlDbType.Date` the parameter will pass just the Date portion to the database.
- `MySqlDbType.DateTime` will save whatever portion of the `DateTime` the DB is setup to accept.

The same is true using `MySqlDbType.Int32` for the Id: rather than converting to string, you can pass the correct data type.